# How to have emacs recognize Makefile as a prefix for makefile-mode?

Tags: major-mode, makefile-mode

I figured the following would tell emacs to recognize files starting with "Makefile" and start makefile-mode:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\`Makefile" . makefile-mode))
```

The `` \\` `` indicates the start of the string.

This doesn't work though. Can someone please explain why and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already an entry `("[Mm]akefile\\'" . makefile-gmake-mode)` in `auto-mode-alist`.

(I figure that you actually wanted to delete the end `\\'` of the regular expression.)

The entry for `xinit` shows how to handle the beginning of a file name:

```
("\\(/\\|\\`\\)\\.\\([kz]shenv\\|xinitrc\\|startxrc\\|xsession\\)\\'" . sh-mode)
```

The main aspect here is that your regular expression must match the full absolute path of the file sans backup-suffixes and remote-file identifications.

So I propose you use something like

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\(/\\|\\`\\)[Mm]akefile" . makefile-gmake-mode))
```

You don't need to care about the existing entry for makefiles since the first matching entry is used.

If you really want to replace the existing entry even if this is not required you can also use the following statement:

```
(setcar (assoc-string "[Mm]akefile\\'" auto-mode-alist) "\\(/\\|\\`\\)[Mm]akefile")
```

Or if you are afraid that the default entry disappears some time in the future you can act in dependence of its existence in `auto-mode-alist`:

```el
(let ((existing-entry (assoc-string "[Mm]akefile\\'" auto-mode-alist)))
  (if existing-entry (setcar existing-entry "\\(/\\|\\`\\)[Mm]akefile")
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\(/\\|\\`\\)[Mm]akefile" . makefile-gmake-mode))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand this mean that it matches on the full path and so I have to either match on `/Makefile` or `Makefile`. Either way, emacs is giving me an error on your proposed code. Adding a quote in front of the `(` fixes it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It was a typo. I added the quote in the answer.

Comment: If I could give you a hundred upvotes, I'd do it -- this has been driving me crazy for weeks, because every time I made changes to , e.g. Makefile.Docker I would get some default mode that would "helpfully" convert my tabs to spaces.. :(